# How to use the same database in different computers

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Me and a friend are developing a database, but we just decided to migrate from sql to mongo due to big irregularities within our data.
However, when we were working with sqlite3 for python, all we had to do was to to put the .db generated at github and pretty much everyone could access the same given database. However we are now having trouble to do the same with mongo, since it relies on connecting in a database server, not an archive. Is there any way I can bypass that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I would advise. The standard way to use MongoDB (and basically every other database) is to set one up on a dedicated server and then connect to that server and work with the data there. You can make local, throwaway databases for playing and testing and if you don't care to persist the data and give others access to it, but if you need the data to be persistent and accessible then you should have a server. Consider something like the [AWS free tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/), which will let you set up a server in the cloud, install MongoDB, and then connect to it over the interwebs and work on it.

Comment: That's usually that way even when the database is supposed to be used as read-only?

Comment: If it's truly read only, you can just carry your own static copies of the data files and stand up mongod processes on top of them, for dev work.